# Set Props from External Source

Tags: reactjs

When a UI event occurs, my top-level React component receives data to use as props from an external object. I'd like to know the correct way to update the component's props to use for the next render.

It seems like one of the component lifecycle methods should handle this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

The code below shows what I've tried:

• **`Root.update`:** Custom method invoked externally once the data is ready. Both of the two techniques shown do work.

• **`Root.getDefaultProps`:** Used to retrieve props for first render.

• **`Root.render`:** This also works, but is redundant on first render.

• **`Root.componentWillUpdate`:** Does not work but seems like it should.

• **`Root.componentWillReceiveProps`:** Wouldn't make sense for this to work; props aren't received from a React component.

```
var Root = React.createClass({

  update: function() {
    this.setProps(Obj.data); // works but setProps is deprecated
    this.props = Obj.data; // always works
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return Obj.pageload(); // works on first render
  },

  componentWillUpdate: function() {
    this.props = Obj.data. // does not work
    this.setProps(Obj.data); // infinite loop
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
    this.props = Obj.data; // does not work
  },

  render: function() {
    this.props = Obj.data; // works but is redundant

    // ...
  },
});
```

Comment: Props are supposed to be immutable. Can you instead use state on your root component and pass it down as a prop to the child components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point you must be calling `React.render` to render that initial root component with your props.

To update the component with new props simply call `React.render` again for the same component on the same Dom element with the new props.

This won't re-mount the component but will in fact simply send the mounted instance your new props and cause it to re-render with them.

If you want to control what happens when your component receives props then take a look at the component lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Thanks for responding; it hadn't occurred to me to try this. When I read the note for the `setProps` docs, I was thinking in terms of calling `render` on the component vs. `React.render`. Very useful to know that doing this doesn't mean that React has to start over from scratch, which is what I would have expected. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  I think it's quite a common issue, due to the wording of the method ;)